# What means "|| {}" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

As in here for example:

```
var h , aa = aa || {} , m = this ,
```

What's the meaning of "|| {}" ?

Comment: `aa = itself OR empty_object`

Answer (score 5):

It prevents you object from being undefined. 
E.g. if you write:

```
a = B || {};
```

and B will be undefined --> you will assign empty object instead of FALSY value (undefined).

Sum up: if value is "falsy value" assign empty object.

Here you have all falsy values:

- undefined
- null
- NaN
- boolean type FALSE value
- simply '0' as number
- empty string variable

Comment: This gets my +1 because it mentions the value can be any "falsy" value

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = aa || {}
```

This is setting a default value for the variable `aa`. If `aa` isn't "truthy" at the time this line executes, it will set it to `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default initialization in case `aa` is *falsy*. If `aa` is falsy (undefined, 0, empty string,...), `aa` is initialized to an empty object.